# in(), out() and both() function do not work in OrientDB 2.2.32 as written in the doc

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I am using OrientDB 2.2.32 and I have a very simple schema: Vertices "Country" and "PA" and Edge (type LINK) "Is_In" which goes from PA to Country.
I am trying what is written in the doc (https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/SQL-Functions.html), that is to say:

```
select both("Is_In") from V
```

to get "all the incoming and outgoing vertices connected with edges with label (class) "Is_In".

It returns nothing, although I have explicitly created 2 vertices PA linked to one vertex Country by an Is_In edge.

I am also trying this:

```
select both() from Country where Name="DE"
```

I understand that this should return all the vertices that are connected to the vertex of class "Country" and has the Name "DE"?

Am I doing something wrong?

------- EDIT------

Actually the Browser does return something, but it does not appear to be Vertices, this is why the Graph interface does not display anything. It seems that what is returned is the @rid.

Any idea why the function both() (or in() or out()) does not return the complete Vertex?

By the way:

```
select both().Name from PA
```

returns also twice the property "Name" of the 1 vertex that is connected to the 2 PA vertices (which is normal).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

out()/in()/both() functions return the RIDs of the connected vertices. You can expand the result with expand() function as follows:

```
select expand(both("Is_In")) from V
```